# awk matching regex and replace the symbol

Tags: regex, awk, sed, gawk

Hi I have a file which has lines as below ( below is a single sample line)

```
Running Test File: 
/home/rsc_app|06_2BIN/08_payfacil/01_5BIN/003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt|Test
Result | Pass | MIG_NT2_EP2 CIS_EP1|0403319|
```

what i am trying to achieve is match the

```
/003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt
```

and change the / as | so the outcome to be ( the text before .UTT can be anything basically it is a file name and .utt is the extension so i want to find the pattern to match .utt and replace the  / to |)

```
|003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt
```

the whole line to be

```
Running Test File:
/home/rsc_app|06_2BIN/08_payfacil/01_5BIN|003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt|Test
Result | Pass | MIG_NT2_EP2 CIS_EP1|0403319|
```

I have tried so many regexp to match but not able to do so . the last one which I tried was as below

```
awk -F["|"] '{if($3~/\/.+?(?=utt)/){sub(/\//,"|",$0)}} {print $0}'
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: also note that lookarounds are not supported by awk.. see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sed 's#/\([^/]*\.utt\)#|\1#'
```

This will match a `/` followed by non-`/` characters ending with `.utt` (except the first `/`, rest are captured in a group to be [backreferenced](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions) in replacement section)

Note that this doesn't specifically restrict the matching to 3rd field

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help you on same(considering your Input_file is same as shown sample):

```
awk 'match($0,/\/003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt/){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "|" substr($0,RSTART+1,1) substr($0,RSTART+2);next} 1'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now:

```
awk '
{
   if(match($0,/\/003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt/)){
     print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "|" substr($0,RSTART+1,1) substr($0,RSTART+2);
     next}
}
1
'   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '
match($0,/\/003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt/){
     print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "|" substr($0,RSTART+1,1) substr($0,RSTART+2);
     next}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @JamesBrown, sorry sir, could you please explain where it is breaking, I will edit the code then, didn't get it. I see output is coming like your output only(apologies if I missed anything here)

Comment: @JamesBrown, cool. Thanks a TON for letting me know fixed it now, you ROCk :)

Comment: @JamesBrown, II caption, done sir thank for always guiding sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `rev` to reverse the text and replace the first `/` with `|`. Using awk:

```
$ rev file | 
  awk '{sub(/\//,"|")}1' | 
  rev
/home/rsc_app|06_2BIN/08_payfacil/01_5BIN|003_nt2bnet_Acq004601_0100_0420_mc.utt|Test
Result | Pass | MIG_NT2_EP2 CIS_EP1|0403319|
```

This makes change on every record so if there are `/`s in other records, use some exclusion rule.

**Edit**: On Sundeep's comment, using GNU awk's `gensub` and greediness:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(.*)\//,"\\1|",$0)}1' file
```

Comment: replacing last occurrence of something is possible with regex too, taking advantage of greediness... `echo 'a/b/c/d/e' | sed 's#\(.*\)/#\1|#'`